# Trying to get data out of the youtube api

Tags: ajax, json, api, youtube-api

So I'm trying to get data out of the youtube api with Ajax. I've tried the following method:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=2&playlistId=PL55713C70BA91BD6E&key=my_key';
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    $.each(data, function () {
            console.log(data);
    });
    });
```

As you can see I've got the url of a random playlist in var url. After that I'm looping through all of that data, and in the end I want to console.log all of the data. It's giving me the following data:

[image]

For some reason it's giving me all the data 5 times as you can see in the screenshot. Also, when I replace 'console.log(data)' by 'console.log(data.items.id)' it says the following in my console:

[image]

For some reason it's giving me all the data x5, and it also doesn't seem to be recognizing 'items'. Does anyone have any idea what went wrong in my code?

Comment: your inner function don't takes a parameter. try `data.forEach(console.log)`

Comment: So I have to replace $.each(data, function () {
            console.log(data);
    }); by what you just typed?

Comment: yes. but it only will write the data into the console.

Comment: Alright, I've done the exact thing u said and it's giving me this error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: or maybe: `data.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e); })`

Comment: then type: `console.log(typeof data); console.log(data);` and tell me what it prints to the console.

Comment: it's still giving me the same error

Comment: didn't see your last comment, but it still gives that error even after that.

Comment: `console.log(typeof data);` should not cause an error... i can see in your link, that it should be an array?!

Comment: what link? and what should be an array?

Comment: you said, it is giving you the following data: http://prntscr.com/7nh7l9

Comment: yes, I've indeed just seen that it's an array. I can now console.log(data.items[0].id); But my array excists out of 2 items. How do I get to display both of those items without having to type that console.log line again? And btw, It's still giving me the data x5. Just look at the following link: http://prntscr.com/7nhhqx

Comment: use `data.forEach(function(e) { e.items.forEach(function(item) { console.log(item.id); }); })` to print all ids of all items of all objects/data.

Comment: It just keeps giving me the same error about data.forEach not being a function

Comment: i thought `data` is an array?!

Comment: data isn't. items is

Comment: `console.log(data.items[0].id);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines would work:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=2&playlistId=PL55713C70BA91BD6E&key={YOUR-API-KEY}';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    data.items.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.snippet.title);
    });
});
```

If you wanted to stick with using the jQuery `each` then you can do:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (key, value) {
            console.log(value.snippet.title);
    });
});
```

The `each` function is going to hand each of the items in the array into your function so you need the `(key, value)` signature so that you can access them in your iterator function.